# Cannot use mutating member on immutable value of type 'String'

Tags: swift, swift3

I need to print `String` inside the `String` extensions. I am aware the addition of one `String` with another `String`. But,

Why below code give me an error?

Is it possible to solve this error with this way?

If yes, How?

**Code:**

```
extension String{

    func fruit(){
        //After some manipulation with self I need to print
        print("Apple".parent("Tree"))
        print("Tomato".parent("Plant"))


    }

    mutating func parent(_ word:String){

        self = self+" "+word

    }
}
```

**Error :**

> Cannot use mutating member on immutable value of type 'String'

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to understand the difference between a non-mutating function that returns a value, and a void mutating function. The one you wrote, is a mutating function:

```
mutating func parent(_ word:String){

    self = self+" "+word

}
```

Mutating functions like this can be used like this:

```
var string = "Hello"
string.parent("World")
print(string)
```

As you can see, the call to `parent` changes the value that is stored in the variable `string`.

---

Function that returns is another matter. This is the same `parent` function, rewritten to return a value:

```
func parent(_ word: String) -> String {
    return self + " " + word
}
```

You can use this function that returns like this:

```
print("Apple".parent("Tree"))
print("Tomato".parent("Plant"))
```

In this case, nothing is being changed. Values are just being "computed" and returned to the caller.

What you are doing wrong is basically **trying to use a mutating function like a function that returns**.

To fix this, either change the function to return a value, or use the mutating function properly, as I've showed you.

Comment: returning is better than assigning to self. +1.

Comment: First Solution : I think `var string = "Hello" ` is poor when I need to print 1000 of separate fruits. Also it gives me an error ` Cannot assign value of type '()' to type 'String?'` and the Second one is good. Thanks for the brief explanation

Answer (score 1):

`parent` is a mutating method, and since `fruit` calls it, `fruit` is mutating as well, and must be declared as such.

Comment: If I make `mutating func fruit()`  also I get error `cannot use mutating member on immutable value of type 'String'`. Can you please elaborate with example?