# Different results with Set altough similar code? What is the excact problem in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, set, intersection, hashable

i have a small problem. I have two Arrays where i try to find the same content in it. So i decided to convert it to a Set and then using those nice functions with "subtract". However i get very different results. Can someone tell me why this happens? When i use "subtracting" instead of "subtract" i get no problems however this is very weird for me and i really have no clue why this happens.

```
   var objectIDsWhichExist = [ "kjugsJHL6JYoByOreUQ0wUefsbX2", "18ixZ21PJDXA1WzeJqZzctl7tTk2", "ZeQPYGfDvWMLSVykb4M5FQ6miGX2"]
    var helperObjectIDsWhichExistInAdded = [ "kjugsJHL6JYoByOreUQ0wUefsbX2", "18ixZ21PJDXA1WzeJqZzctl7tTk2"]
    


    var setA = Set(objectIDsWhichExist) /* Updated Data*/
    var setB = Set(helperObjectIDsWhichExistInAdded) /* Standard Data*/
    let different = setA.subtract(setB) // I GET HERE ()  
    print(different) // I GET THIS RESULT "()\n"
```

And this is the one sample which works, surprisingly. However i still dont know really why???

```
    var employees: Set = Set(objectIDsWhichExist)
    let neighbors: Set = Set(helperObjectIDsWhichExistInAdded)
    employees.subtract(neighbors)
    print(employees) // HERE IT DOES WORK because i get this -> ["ZeQPYGfDvWMLSVykb4M5FQ6miGX2"]\n"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`subtract`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/1779475-subtract) and [`subtracting`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/1783322-subtracting) both computes the difference of 2 sets, but `subtract` is *mutating*, whereas `subtracting` is not.

This means that `x.subtract(y)` *changes* the set `x` to the computed difference, whereas `x.subtracting(y)` doesn't change `x` at all, and instead *returns* the difference. On the other hand, `subtract` returns nothing (`Void`).

When you do

```
let different = setA.subtract(setB) // I GET HERE ()  
print(different)
```

you see `()` being printed, because that is what the string representation of `Void` looks like - an empty tuple.

This works

```
employees.subtract(neighbors)
print(employees)
```

because `subtract` changes `employee`.

This also works:

```
let different = setA.subtracting(setB)
print(different)
```

because the return value of `subtracting` - the set difference - is assigned to `different`. Note that this doesn't change `setA`.

This doesn't work:

```
employees.subtracting(neighbors)
print(employees) // still shows the original employees
```

Because `subtracting` doesn't change `employees`, and you are ignoring its return value.

There are many other pairs of such mutating vs non-mutating methods, like

- `Set.formUnion` vs `Set.union`
- `String.append` vs `String.appending`

[Related post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45451133/5133585)

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining this in detail. Thank you really very much for this that you took your time to give me an excellent answer like this!